# How to show Product Related News in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have installed WooCommerce in WordPress and everything is working fine. I want to show Product related articles on Product page. Can anyone tell me which logic I must have to use to do it? I dont want to use any plugin, just give me idea how I can do it.

I think these ideas can work:

- Adding same taxonomies for both Products and Articles and then display it.
- Adding Same custom Fields or tags to products and articles.
- Let the user choose which articles must have to display on product page.

I am not sure about them, If anyone have any suggestions then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add a meta field in your products that relates back to your articles.
Either by category or ID (your choice). Then on the product page you can loop through your posts and display them that way